# Integral of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{1+x^2}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, improper-integrals

I tried to evaluate the following:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{1+x^2}dx$$

where $W(x)$ is the Lambert $W$ function

but without a great ending, I tried to use Mellin transform or some stuff but no success.

Edit:
This is what I get with Mellin transform.

Let $$I(t)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{1+(tx)^2}dx$$

Taking the Mellin transform: $$M(I(t);s)= \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{1+(tx)^2}t^{s-1}dtdx$$

Let $$\Omega= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{1+(tx)^2}dt= x^{-s} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t^{s-1}}{1+t^2}dt= \frac{x^{-s}}{2} \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi s/2)}$$

and now $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{x^s}dx = (s-1)^{s-3} \Gamma(2-s)$$

Now we have to take the inverse Mellin transform of this:

$$\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{(s-1)^{s-3} \Gamma(2-s) }{\sin(s\pi/2)}$$

Comment: Do you know if this integral has a closed form?

Comment: The substitution $W(x)=y$ will make the integrand elementary. Also, try the geometric series for $\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{1-(-x^2)}$. You could add more detail on your Mellin transform attempt too. Partial fractions on the $\frac1{x^2+1}$ could work.

Comment: @TymaGaidash The substitution $W(x) = y$ does NOT make the integral elementary. Also the Geometric Series can be used when $|x| < 1$ which in that range is not.

Comment: @KurtGödel That is why “integrand” was written.

Comment: i do some edit to show you what i do

Comment: It [equals](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=1%2F2+i+%28-1%2F%281+-+i+e%5Ex+x%29+-+x%2F%281+-+i+e%5Ex+x%29+%2B+1%2F%281+%2B+i+e%5Ex+x%29+%2B+x%2F%281+%2B+i+e%5Ex+x%29%29), maybe with limits,  $\frac i2\left(\int_0^\infty \frac x{ixe^x+1}dx+\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{ixe^x+1}+\int_0^\infty\frac{x}{ixe^x-1}+\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{ixe^x-1}\right)$

Answer (score 3):

I don't dare to say there is no close for for this integral. I've witnessed enough to believe there will be someone who will find it, or something close.

I can suggest something ways humbler.
To get rid of $W(x)$ consider the substitution

$$x = t e^t \qquad \qquad \text{d}x = (t+1)e^t$$

Indeed for $x = te^t$ we have $W(te^t) = t$. Thence:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{t e^t(t+1)}{1 + t^2 e^{2t}}\ \text{d}t$$

This is not an elementary integral, and perhaps it can be attacked with some numerical methods.

What I can say, is that the integral does converge (as does your, obviously), and it converges to the value:

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{W(x)}{1+x^2}\ \text{d}x \approx 1.131016898112286(...)$$

Comment: I also tried Feynman tricks, let $I(t)=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{1+(tx)^2}dx$                           with some algebra i find that  $I'(t)= -\frac{2}{t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{W(x)}{2+(tx)^2}dx$ it was almost close...

Comment: i have edit my post for some more information